# Can't show markers in map

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a newbie in React Native, and i'm trying to make an app with events that happen around a city.
I have a firebase database with data related to the events.
I'm trying to show the markers on the map with the coordinates inserted in the database, but nothing shows up. No errors, just nothing showing.

Here is my **firebase:**
[image]

The **tree view** of the project:

[image]

My **Marker.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './styles';
import { MapView } from 'expo';

const Marker = ({
  id, latitude, longitude, image, title, categorie, date, hour, city, location, description,
}) => (
  <MapView.Marker
    stopPropagation={true}
    identifier={id}
    coordinate={{
      latitude: latitude,
      longitude: longitude
    }}
    image={image}
    title={title}
    categorie={categorie}
    date={date}
    hour={hour}
    city={city}
    location={location}
    description={description}
  />
);

export default Marker;
```

My **Map.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { MapView } from 'expo';
import Marker from './Marker';
import styles from './styles';

const Map = ({
  region, markers,
}) => (
  <MapView
    style={{flex:1}}
    region={region}
    provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
  >
    {markers.map(
      (marker) => <Marker key={marker.id} {...marker} />
    )}
  </MapView>
);

export default Map;
```

and finnaly my **Mapa.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, ScrollView, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { MapView, Location, Permissions } from "expo";
import Map from '../components/Map';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import _ from 'lodash';



export default class Mapa extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            region: {
                latitude: 38.725209,
                longitude: -9.150098,
                latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            },
            markers: [],
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this._getLocationAsync();
        this._loadMarkersDatabase();
    }

    _loadMarkersDatabase() {
        firebase.database().ref('markers').once('value', (snapshot) => {
            const values = snapshot.val();
            if (values) {
                const markers = [];
                _.map(values, (val, key) => {
                    const marker = {
                        ...val,
                        identifier: key,
                    };
                    markers.push(marker);
                });
                this.setState({ markers });
            }
        });
    }

    async _getLocationAsync() {
        const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
        // status for permission, if accepted or not
        // console.log('status: ', status);
        if (status !== 'granted') {
            alert('Permission to access location was denied');
        }

        const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});

        // fetch markers in state
        const markers = this.state.markers;
        // setup new marker coordinates
        const initialMarker = {
            latitude: location.coords.latitude,
            longitude: location.coords.longitude,
        };
        // add marker to firebase with push, so it generates an identifier
        const firebaseMarker = firebase.database().ref('markers').push({
            ...initialMarker
        });
        // new reference from firebase, where we can fetch the generated key
        // console.log(firebaseMarker);
        // fetch generated key
        initialMarker.identifier = firebaseMarker.getKey();
        // add new marker to array loaded from state
        markers.push(initialMarker);

        // set state with new region from user coordinates, and new marker from that location
        this.setState({
            region: {
                latitude: location.coords.latitude,
                longitude: location.coords.longitude,
                latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            },
            markers,
        });
    };



    render() {
        const { region, markers } = this.state;
        return(
            <Map
                style={styles.map}
                region={this.state.region}
                markers={this.state.markers}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: debug console to marker data such as lat,long ? and map view is dsiplay?

Comment: sorry, didn't understand what you're asking. The map is displayed. Don't know why, can't seem to debug console in map view